# Where can I ask questions about psychologist-client relationships?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where can I ask some questions about psychologist-client relationships, in terms of ethical codes of psychology?

Comment: Not sure if it's considered on topic on any current site. There's a [psychology](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/79476/psychology) proposal that might entertain it but it's not open yet. Oh, wait, apparently there's [Cognitive sciences](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/)... maybe there? I've no clue what's on topic there so you should definitely look at their help pages and their Meta site.

Comment: You can use @Catija's suggestions, and as additional info, I've searched some tags on the suggested sites and can't find any specifically relating to your topic. Read the help centers for those sites (mainly what is on topic info) and if that doesn't make it clear, it might be worth asking on the site's Meta.

Answer (score 2):

Their help center doesn't say one way or the other, but try [Health](http://health.stackexchange.com).  I asked [whether questions about the practice of medicine are on-topic](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/262/290) and, while the consensus isn't clear, the only answer to that question so far is +7 and in favor.  On the other hand, I don't see tags for "ethics" or "client"-anything.

Medical ethics and client confidentiality are not concerns specific to psychology; they apply to all medical fields.  Health is a young beta site, so if they don't have questions about this yet, maybe you'll help shape their scope!